# Why does deleting the columns before giving it to interleave work but sometimes it does NOT work and how to fix it with simple code?

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

Why does deleting the columns before giving it to interleave work but sometimes it does NOT work?

Code snipt:

```
        # -Interleaving datasets
        print('- Interleaving datasets')
        datasets = [my_load_dataset(path, name, data_files).with_format("torch") for path, name, data_files in zip(path, name, data_files)]
        # datasets = [my_load_dataset(path, name).with_format("torch") for path, name in zip(path, name)]
        if path[0] == 'parquet':  # idk why I need to do this, I checked very carefully and deleted all columns so interleaved data set matched but when doing this with c4 & wikitext it fails but with the parquet it works
            dataset_descriptions = [dataset.description for dataset in datasets]  # print description if available
            print(f'{dataset_descriptions=}')
            # - make sure all datasets have the same columns to avoid interleave to complain
            all_columns = [col for dataset in datasets for col in dataset.column_names]
            print(f'{all_columns=}')
            columns_to_remove = [col for dataset in datasets for col in dataset.column_names if col != 'text']
            columns_to_remove = list(set(columns_to_remove))  # remove duplicates
            print(f'{columns_to_remove=}')
            datasets = [dataset.remove_columns(columns_to_remove) for dataset in datasets]
            # - interleave
            print(f'{probabilities=}')
            dataset_descriptions = [dataset.description for dataset in datasets]  # print description if available
            print(f'{dataset_descriptions=}')
        dataset = interleave_datasets(datasets, probabilities)
        # dataset = dataset.remove_columns(columns_to_remove)
        print(f'{dataset=}')
        print(f'{dataset.column_names=}')
    print(f'{dataset=}')
    print(f'{type(dataset)=}')
    # datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset
    # datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset
    # dataset = IterableDataset(dataset) if type(dataset) != IterableDataset else dataset  # to force dataset.take(batch_size) to work in non-streaming mode
    batch = dataset.take(batch_size)
    print(f'{batch=}')
    print(f'{next(iter(batch))=}')
```

code:

```
def experiment_compute_diveristy_coeff_single_dataset_then_combined_datasets_with_domain_weights():
    """
    Get divs using pt ft, pt (rand, rand ft?) 
    - div c4 
    - div wt = wt-103
    Then with unioned datasets
    - div c4+wt, uniform [0.5, 0.5]
    - # div c4+wt, data set size proportions (using GBs)
    - div c4+wt, respect doremi
    - div c4+wt, respect the pile
    - div c4+wt, respect gpt3 weights
    then repeat all with pt (no ft)
    """
    import random
    from diversity.data_mixtures import get_uniform_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103, get_doremi_based_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103, get_llama_v1_based_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103
    probabilities = []
    data_mixture_name = None
    streaming = True
    data_files = []
    seed = 0
    # -- Setup wandb
    import wandb
    # - Dryrun
    mode = 'dryrun'; num_batches = 3
    # mode = 'dryrun'; num_batches = 3; seed = random.randint(0, 2**32 - 1)

    # - Online (real experiment)
    # mode='online'; num_batches = 600; seed = random.randint(0, 2**32 - 1)
    # path, name = 'c4', 'en'
    # path, name = "wikitext", 'wikitext-103-v1'
    path, name, data_files = ['c4', 'wikitext'], ['en', 'wikitext-103-v1'], [None, None]
    probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_uniform_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103()
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_doremi_based_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103()
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_llama_v1_based_data_mixture_for_c4_wt103()
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = [0.75, 0.25], '[0.75, 0.25]' 
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = [0.25, 0.75], '[0.25, 0.75]' 
    # path, name = 'EleutherAI/pile', 'all'
    # path, name = 'conceptofmind/pile_cc', 'sep_ds'
    # streaming = False
    # path, name = 'conceptofmind/pile_cc', 'sep_ds'
    # path, name = 'EleutherAI/pile', 'hacker_news' 
    # path, name = 'EleutherAI/pile', 'nih_exporter'  # https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/6144
    # path, name = 'EleutherAI/pile', 'pubmed' 
    # path, name = 'EleutherAI/pile', 'uspto' 
    # - 5 subsets of pile using hf data set viewer (parquet)) 
    # from diversity.pile_subset_urls import urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto
    # path, name, data_files = 'parquet', 'hacker_news', urls_hacker_news
    # path, name, data_files = 'parquet', 'nih_exporter', urls_nih_exporter
    # path, name, data_files = 'parquet', 'pubmed', urls_pubmed
    # path, name, data_files = 'parquet', 'uspto', urls_uspto
    # - 5 subsets of the pile interleaved
    # from diversity.pile_subset_urls import urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto
    # from diversity.data_mixtures import get_doremi_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile, get_llama_v1_data_mixtures_5subsets_of_pile
    # path, name, data_files = ['conceptofmind/pile_cc'] + ['parquet'] * 4, ['sep_ds'] + ['hacker_news', 'nih_exporter', 'pubmed', 'uspto'], [None] + [urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto]
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = [1.0/len(path)] * len(path), f'{[1.0/len(path)] * len(path)=}'
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_doremi_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile(name)
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_llama_v1_data_mixtures_5subsets_of_pile(name)
    # not changing
    batch_size = 512
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-m%m-d%d-t%Hh_%Mm_%Ss')
    run_name = f'{path} div_coeff_{num_batches=} ({today=} ({name=}) {data_mixture_name=} {probabilities=})'
    print(f'\n---> {run_name=}\n')

    # - Init wandb
    debug: bool = mode == 'dryrun'
    run = wandb.init(mode=mode, project="beyond-scale", name=run_name, save_code=True)
    wandb.config.update({"num_batches": num_batches, "path": path, "name": name, "today": today, 'probabilities': probabilities, 'batch_size': batch_size, 'debug': debug, 'data_mixture_name': data_mixture_name, 'streaming': streaming, 'data_files': data_files, 'seed': seed})
    # run.notify_on_failure() # https://community.wandb.ai/t/how-do-i-set-the-wandb-alert-programatically-for-my-current-run/4891
    print(f'{debug=}')
    print(f'{wandb.config=}')

    # -- Get probe network
    from datasets import load_dataset 
    from datasets.iterable_dataset import IterableDataset
    import torch
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    probe_network = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    probe_network = probe_network.to(device)

    # -- Get data set
    def my_load_dataset(path, name, data_files=data_files):
        print(f'{path=} {name=} {streaming=} {data_files=}')
        if path == 'json' or path == 'bin' or path == 'csv':
            print(f'{data_files_prefix+name=}')
            return load_dataset(path, data_files=data_files_prefix+name, streaming=streaming, split="train").with_format("torch")
        elif path == 'parquet':
            print(f'{data_files=}')
            return load_dataset(path, data_files=data_files, streaming=streaming, split="train").with_format("torch")
        else:
            return load_dataset(path, name, streaming=streaming, split="train").with_format("torch")
    # - get data set for real now
    if isinstance(path, str):
        dataset = my_load_dataset(path, name)
    else:
        # -Interleaving datasets
        print('- Interleaving datasets')
        datasets = [my_load_dataset(path, name, data_files).with_format("torch") for path, name, data_files in zip(path, name, data_files)]
        # datasets = [my_load_dataset(path, name).with_format("torch") for path, name in zip(path, name)]
        if path[0] == 'parquet':  # idk why I need to do this, I checked very carefully and deleted all columns so interleaved data set matched but when doing this with c4 & wikitext it fails but with the parquet it works
            dataset_descriptions = [dataset.description for dataset in datasets]  # print description if available
            print(f'{dataset_descriptions=}')
            # - make sure all datasets have the same columns to avoid interleave to complain
            all_columns = [col for dataset in datasets for col in dataset.column_names]
            print(f'{all_columns=}')
            columns_to_remove = [col for dataset in datasets for col in dataset.column_names if col != 'text']
            columns_to_remove = list(set(columns_to_remove))  # remove duplicates
            print(f'{columns_to_remove=}')
            datasets = [dataset.remove_columns(columns_to_remove) for dataset in datasets]
            # - interleave
            print(f'{probabilities=}')
            dataset_descriptions = [dataset.description for dataset in datasets]  # print description if available
            print(f'{dataset_descriptions=}')
        dataset = interleave_datasets(datasets, probabilities)
        # dataset = dataset.remove_columns(columns_to_remove)
        print(f'{dataset=}')
        print(f'{dataset.column_names=}')
    print(f'{dataset=}')
    print(f'{type(dataset)=}')
    # datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset
    # datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset
    # dataset = IterableDataset(dataset) if type(dataset) != IterableDataset else dataset  # to force dataset.take(batch_size) to work in non-streaming mode
    batch = dataset.take(batch_size)
    print(f'{batch=}')
    print(f'{next(iter(batch))=}')
    column_names = next(iter(batch)).keys()
    print(f'{column_names=}')

    # - Prepare functions to tokenize batch
    def preprocess(examples):
        return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", max_length=128, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    remove_columns = column_names  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader
    def map(batch):
        return batch.map(preprocess, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    print(f'{batch=}')
    tokenized_batch = map(batch)
    print(f'{next(iter(tokenized_batch))=}')

    # -- Compute diversity coefficient
    print(f'-- Compute diversity coefficient')
    print(f'{seed=}, {streaming=}')
    # - Debug run
    # results: dict = get_diversity_coefficient(dataset, map, probe_network, num_batches=3, seed=seed, debug=True, shuffle=False)  # (quick debug) hardcoded for debugging
    # results: dict = get_diversity_coefficient(dataset, map, probe_network, num_batches=3, seed=seed, debug=True, shuffle=True)  # (slow debug) hardcoded for debugging
    # results: dict = get_diversity_coefficient(dataset, map, probe_network, num_batches=3, seed=seed, debug=False, shuffle=False)  # (real) hardcoded for debugging
    # - Real run
    # assert not debug, f'Err: {debug=} for real run'
    results: dict = get_diversity_coefficient(dataset, map, probe_network, num_batches=num_batches, seed=seed, debug=debug, shuffle=False)
    # results: dict = get_diversity_coefficient(dataset, map, probe_network, num_batches=num_batches, seed=seed, debug=debug, shuffle=True)
    # - Log results
    div_coeff, div_coeff_ci = results['div_coeff'], results['div_coeff_ci']
    print(f'{div_coeff=} {div_coeff_ci=}')
    wandb.log({'div_coeff': div_coeff, 'div_coeff_ci': div_coeff_ci})

    # -- Save results or not
    save_results = True
    if save_results:
        output_dir = Path(f'~/data/div_coeff/{today}').expanduser()
        output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        np.save(output_dir / f'distance_matrix{today}.npy', results['distance_matrix'])
        np.save(output_dir / f'results{today}.npy', results)
        # Save results as a pretty-printed JSON
        results = {key: str(value) for key, value in results.items()}
        with open(output_dir / f'results{today}.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(results, f, indent=4)
        # - wandb save
        base_path = str(output_dir.parent)
        wandb.save(str(output_dir / f'distance_matrix{today}.npy'), base_path=base_path)
        wandb.save(str(output_dir / f'results{today}.npy'), base_path=base_path)
        wandb.save(str(output_dir / f'results{today}.json'), base_path=base_path)
        wandb.save(__file__)
    
    # -- Finish wandb
    wandb.finish()
```

err

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
'timestamp'
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 729, in _iter
    del transformed_example[c]
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 652, in __iter__
    yield from self._iter()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 73, in __next__
    result = next(self.it)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 400, in __iter__
    yield next(iterators[i])
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1013, in __iter__
    yield from islice(self.ex_iterable, self.n)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1353, in __iter__
    for key, example in ex_iterable:
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 531, in experiment_compute_diveristy_coeff_single_dataset_then_combined_datasets_with_domain_weights
    print(f'{next(iter(batch))=}')
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 592, in <module>
    experiment_compute_diveristy_coeff_single_dataset_then_combined_datasets_with_domain_weights()
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

hf discuss: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-does-deleting-the-columns-before-giving-it-to-interleave-work-but-sometimes-it-does-not-work/50879